# getting an error in where laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have on input as `amount` and also getting the discount price but getting an error in where condition,

Here is my query,

```
public function getDiscountProducts(Request $request){

        $amount = $request->input('amount');

        $products = DB::table('products')
        ->select(DB::raw('(((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount'))
        ->where(DB::raw('(((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount'), $amount)
        ->get();

   
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'All categories Products',
            'code' => 200,
            'data' => $products,
            'status' => 'success'
        ]);
    }
```

Please check where I am missing,

Error:

> "Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS discount is null' at line 1 (SQL: select (((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount from products where (((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount is null)"

Comment: what error are you getting? and I assume you are trying to find where 'discount' is `$amount`?

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS discount is null' at line 1 (SQL: select (((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount from `products` where (((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount is null)

Comment: why are you not doing the where on 'discount'?  `where('discount', ...)` ?

Comment: tried, but getting error,  Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'discount' in 'where clause' (SQL: select (((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount from `products` where `discount` is null)

Comment: did you notice that `$amount` is `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line

```
->where(DB::raw('(((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp) AS discount'), $amount)
```

to

```
->where(DB::raw('(((mrp - price) * 100) / mrp)'), $amount)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `AS discount` from where condition.